# How to invoke method with variable arguments in java using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method with variable arguments using java reflection. Here's the class which hosts the method:

```
public class TestClass {

public void setParam(N ... n){
    System.out.println("Calling set param...");
}
```

Here's the invoking code :

```
try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.test.reflection.TestClass");
        Method  method = c.getMethod ("setParam", com.test.reflection.N[].class);
        method.invoke(c, new com.test.reflection.N[]{});
```

I'm getting IllegalArgumentException in the form of "wrong number of arguments" at the last line where I'm calling invoke. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

- Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public class Test {

public void setParam(N... n) {
    System.out.println("Calling set param...");
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test t=new Test();
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("test.Test");
    Method  method = c.getMethod ("setParam", N[].class);
    method.invoke(t, (Object) new N[]{});
}
}
```

Works for me.

1. Cast your N[] to Object
2. call invoke on instance, not on class

Comment: Tried that without cast to `(Object)` - I get the same exception as you did. So just add the cast (and correct point no 1) and you will be fine.

Comment: Right on, I was missing the cast to Object[]. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Shamik: if you know the method you want to call you may avoid such issues using dp4j

Answer (score 3):

There is no `TestClass` instance in your code snippet on which the methd is invoked. You need an *instance* of the `TestClass`, and not just the `TestClass` itself. Call `newInstance()` on `c`, and use the result of this call as the first argument of `method.invoke()`.

Moreover, to make sure your array is considered as one argument, and not a varargs, you need to cast it to Object:

```
m.invoke(testClassInstance, (Object) new com.test.reflection.N[]{});
```

Comment: I thought so and tried that earlier. Here's what I did. Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.test.reflection.TestClass");
   Object iClass = c.newInstance();Method  method = c.getMethod ("setParam", com.test.reflection.N[].class);
        method.invoke(iClass , new com.test.reflection.N[]{}); I get "wrong number of arguments" exception.